# junit not work @autowired

Tags: java, spring, junit

I'm getting an error autowired bean. Outside the test classes it works. What is being done wrong? how to raise the application context. even specify which parts? Here is my code:

```
<properties>
      <java-version>1.6</java-version>
      <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>      
 </properties>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

root-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<import resource="hibernate-config.xml"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    //
</bean>
```

```
  @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
  @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-  context.xml" })

 public class AdminManagerTest5 {

@Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Test
public void t(){
    System.out.print(sessionFactory);

}
```

}

hibernate-config

```
  bean id="sessionFactory"       class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>WEB-INF/spring/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
```

ERROR

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [WEB-      INF/spring/hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:179)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:642)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 41 more
```

P.S.Sorry for my english

Comment: Where are the other Spring dependencies? Show the other dependencies of your pom.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

Your `sessionFactory` configuration is pointing to

```
<property name="configLocation">
    <value>WEB-INF/spring/hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
</property>
```

but the directory `WEB-INF/spring` is not added to the classpath and therefore Spring cannot find it.

You'll need to either specify a `file:` prefixed path (relative or absolute) or put the file somewhere that will be in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

You're using spring-test 4.0 with other spring jars of version 3.1.0.RELEASE. Don't do that. Use spring-test 3.1.0, or use the 4.0 version of all the other spring jars, but don't mix incompatible versions together.

Comment: if i use spring-test 3.1.0.RELEASE, a have java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Comment: Then read the exception stack trace and message, find the cause of the exception and fix it.

Comment: I do not know how to fix it. hibernate.cfg.xml file path is specified.

Comment: stack trace I posted above, along with the files

Comment: First of all, there are extra spaces in `WEB-    INF`. Second, WEB-INF/spring/hibernate.cfg.xml is not a classpath resource. It's a web application resource. And your unit tests are not running in a web application. Configure your tests with a config file that is appropriate for the unit tests. Not with a config file that is appropriate for a web application.

Comment: I will be very grateful if you could tell me how to set up these files.